# JAVA generics constructor issue

Tags: java

I'm studying JAVA generics nowadays and find out some weird situation.

```
class A{
    public void mInA(){
        System.out.println("mInA");
    }
}

interface I{
    public void mInInterfaceI();
}

class B extends A implements I{
    public void mInInterfaceI(){
        System.out.println("mInterfaceI");
    }
}

class MyList <TP1, TP2>{
    MyList(TP1 data1){
        this.data1 = data1;
    }

    TP1 data1;
    TP2 data2;
    MyList<TP1, TP2> next;
}

public class GenericPrepare {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        B obj = new B();

        MyList<A,B> anchor = new MyList<>(obj);//Curious

        anchor.data2 = new B();
        anchor.next = null;
    }
}
```

My constructor is designed to put TP1 as input. So I must input 'A' type reference as argument in above remark.
But when i input 'B' type reference as argument, JAVA is not complaining about it.
I have no idea what's going on here.

Comment: Are you sure "Java is not complaining about it"? My compiler _does_ complain about it. Can you show how exactly you compiled your code?

Comment: @Sweeper I attached my full story.

Comment: Aha, now that's better. It's because `B` inherits from `A`, so `B` _is a kind of_ `A`.

Comment: @Sweeper Thankyou:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MyList<A,B> constructor expects an A object as parameter, but because B extends A, B is actually assignable to A -> your code works.